# JSON > C# Class (Specific Ones Only)

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have a database that I can convert to a JSON file, which has it all nice and neat for me.

[image: databse image]

Now, let's say I wanted to fetch information for only specific types. For example, the `ID`, the `Category`, and the `Targets`. How would I get the information from those types while ignoring the rest? Is this possible? If it is possible, what tool should I use to get this done? I currently have JSON.Net, would that one be suitable? And if so, how would I go about getting that said data from the larger set without modifying the JSON file?

Comment: Your question is not clear but JSON.Net library is well suited for any kind of JSON manipulation in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is trivial to do so with JSON.Net. Simply create a class that only has those three properties and deserialize the JSON using that class. For the full set, create another class that has all the properties and deserialize the JSON using that class.

However, we usually deserialize the JSON to one class with the full set of properties and use what we need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass this information to a model you cant to it directly the best way it could be with a stored procedure and then in your C# project make this new model of the data you want to receive and that's all.

**Example of stored procedure**

```
USE Database;  
GO  
  IF OBJECT_ID('sp_selectTable', 'P') IS NOT NULL  
  DROP PROCEDURE sp_selectTable;  
GO  
  CREATE PROCEDURE sp_selectTable  
AS    
  SET NOCOUNT ON;  
  SELECT Column1, Column1,Column3
  FROM Table 
  RETURN  
GO
```

**Example of your model**

```
public class Model
{
 public int Column1 { get; set; }
 public int Column2 { get; set; }
 public int Column3 { get; set; }
}
```

and then call the stored procedure

```
 var result=dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<List<Model>>(sqlQuery).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: sorry my mistake